# Warning from DataNucleus initialization: Database Adapter (JDBC driver) doesnt support specification of schema name in table definitions

Tags: datanucleus

Getting warning during datanucleus' initialization. Can I ignore it?

```
[main] WARN DataNucleus.Datastore  - Default Schema name "databasename" has been specified yet the Database Adapter (JDBC driver) doesnt support specification of schema name in table definitions !
```

Environment:

Datanucleus version: datanucleus-rdbms-5.1.0-release

JDK 8

mysql-connector-java-8.0.11

relevant part of jdoconfig.xml:

```
    <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/databasename?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false&amp;nullCatalogMeansCurrent=true"/>
```

Comment: Why not post the relevant CLASS definition? because somewhere you have specified "schema" and MySQL doesn't do "schema", instead using "catalog" ... and FWIW there are many later releases on the 5.1 branch, so makes no sense to use old things

Comment: The lack of any post back implies you fixed this in your code. Maybe you should post back here as to where your error was.